# Where to find human teeth icon set with all sides?

Tags: vector, icon, stock-images, resource-recommendations

I need human teeth icons in vector format like the attached image with teeth showing from all sides. On all marketplaces (flaticon.com, freepik.com, thenounproject.com, shutterstock.com and graphicriver.net) where I searched for this I only found single teeth icons.

Anyone know where to find a complete vector set?

[image]

Comment: need vector or image

Comment: If you included the word *icon* in your searches, that could explain why you did not find what you were looking for. "Icons" are images for a very specific purpose. You are looking for a plain 'image', nothing more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this of any use? https://www.shutterstock.com/image-vector/form-table-dental-periodontal-charting-vector-356669438?language=en&utm_medium=Affiliate&utm_campaign=Eezy%20Inc&utm_source=38919&irgwc=1

If you look at the related there are some other examples.

Also:

https://www.vecteezy.com/vector-art/87817-vector-dental-charts

Answer (score 0):

[Teeth 1](https://www.google.co.in/search?sa=G&hl=en-IN&tbs=simg:CAEShwIJmo5tTG-0-v4a-wELEKjU2AQaBAgJCAoMCxCwjKcIGmIKYAgDEiinE8kdphOoE4gIgQjKHfgHpROJCOUz0DPRM8A_1wT_1_1PMM0yz37KJQ9GjBi7JFCXv0IwzmepJkephH73EiR83_1eMKavEch5awA80zPwOr1UKuttuVvdnjmOIiQgBAwLEI6u_1ggaCgoICAESBCI7gVEMCxCd7cEJGmcKFwoFbWV0YWzapYj2AwoKCC9tLzA0dDdsChsKCG1hdGVyaWFs2qWI9gMLCgkvbS8wMWwweTAKFwoEZHJ1Z9qliPYDCwoJL20vMDJramJfChYKBWFuZ2xl2qWI9gMJCgcvbS8wbXdjDA&q=periodontal%20charting&tbm=isch&ved=0ahUKEwiX3evLhd3RAhXKKJQKHWv7AfkQsw4IKg&biw=1366&bih=657)

[Teeth 2](https://www.shutterstock.com/image-vector/3d-human-teeth-icons-set-dental-408916441?src=fdOqeb_XS6fKxCkaxcPvsQ-1-33)

[Teeth 3](http://www.opendental.com/manual/sheetsspecial.html)

[Teeth 4](http://technologyadvice.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/curve-dental-2.png)

[Teeth 5](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=&hl=en-IN&tbm=isch&tbs=rimg:CTprrm4b0wKEIjiQJZSn9ZbXsfNV_1UmxEteK_1a9why8aredcb1z5Cy7Y-X-zCiKfjFSUQsvU4OxM64lUUgMIr3LgTCoSCZAllKf1ltexEZE7vKcxMyPhKhIJ81X9SbES14oR38IkMZEmJuQqEgn9r3CHLxqt5xEPKCvZeMlW4ioSCVxvXPkLLtj5Ea6B_1rFWKsEVKhIJf7MKIp-MVJQRMkPnHl5c9wYqEglCy9Tg7EzriRFT3G5tWmdAWioSCVRSAwivcuBMEYF3lVka7xIA&tbo=u&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi729iwht3RAhULpZQKHVsoBxQQ9C8ICQ&biw=1366&bih=657&dpr=1)